# Alter form field inside webforms

Tags: 8, hooks, webforms

I have created a custom module in order to alter a webform that I created in the admin in drupal 8. I need to add ajax function to some fields. My problem is that I can not retrieve the field inside the hook_form_alter (even the title remains the same).
I paste below the function and what I ve tried so far:

```
function customvisit_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {    

$form['elements']['waiting_date_one']['#title'] = t('345');

$form['waiting_date_one'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Title'),
        '#description' => t('Description.'),
        '#weight' => 100,
        '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => '::myAjaxCallback', 
    'disable-refocus' => FALSE, .
    'event' => 'change',
    'wrapper' => 'edit-output', 
    'progress' => [
      'type' => 'throbber',
      'message' => t('Verifying entry...'),
    ],
  ]
    );
}
```

Comment: `$form['elements']['waiting_date_one']['#title'] = t('345');` should've worked. Make sure your module is enabled. If enabled, also make sure the module's name is `customvisit` and that `waiting_date_one` is indeed the key name of the field.

Comment: Also, if you're using multi page, it needs to be `$form['elements']['page_key']['field_key']['#title'] = t('345');`...

Comment: Rather than playing the guessing game and chasing rainbows. Install [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module and enable its Kint module, and do `kint($form);` and you can see there exactly how the structure needs to be.

Comment: @NoSssweat thanks. I should try with page_key. How do I print it with echo in order to include it?

Comment: Check the webform's UI build, it tells you all the key values there.